# How much would a glue bomb cost?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew

My players got a couple Glue Bombs off some Kobolds. You can throw one of these things to restrain creatures (they get a reasonably easy save) until they break free. The players made good use of these bombs against some fleeing enemies, so they want to have a couple more on hand for future encounters.

Considering the originals were made by Kobolds, I'm guessing they weren't altogether hard to make. Likewise, I would imagine they can't be altogether expensive to pick up a few.

What might a Glue Bomb cost?  Alternatively, is there another, somewhat similar item I might base the price of a Glue Bomb on?

(I notice in the PHB that Alchemists's Fire is 50gp. That seems high to me, but I'm not really sure.)

Comment: Don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1):

### Pretty sure they don't exist in the core rules, but...

If DMs Guild stuff is OK (and it sounds like you're the DM, so that's likely up to you), the mini-supplement *Solve et Coagula* covers alchemy and has stuff like a *tanglefoot bag* and other classic D&D alchemy bits.

http://www.dmsguild.com/product/191496/Solve-et-Coagula-A-Practical-Guide-to-Alchemy

Comment: Have you used this supplement? Do you know if it "plays well"?

Comment: I haven't, though I've read it; I'm not sure how many hours or how wide a variety of situations are required to merit posting an answer to this question, which has no core RAW answer at all.